# Only the map legend appearing in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I am trying to plot data on a map. However, only the legend appears on a blank graph. The data set.

```
structure(list(States.Uts = c("Jammu and Kashmir", "Karnataka", 
"Odisha", "Sikkim", "Madhya Pradesh", "Maharashtra", "Kerala", 
"Rajasthan", "Delhi", "Andhra Pradesh", "Uttar Pradesh", "Gujarat", 
"West Bengal", "Mizoram", "Uttarakhand", "Assam", "Haryana", 
"Himachal Pradesh", "Jharkhand", "Punjab"), id = c(35, 8, 36, 
25, 11, 12, 9, 21, 5, 17, 24, 22, 1, 30, 23, 26, 6, 19, 7, 20
), long = c(74.8692906760123, 76.1671602023197, 84.4299347735266, 
88.47355094813, 78.2889834734203, 76.1073683433136, 76.4080579710788, 
73.8499033398323, 77.1154800785184, 79.964340328073, 80.5663333555389, 
71.5737853588608, 87.9835046818375, 92.8318089515678, 79.2071970183086, 
92.8261810120493, 76.3401988564537, 77.2453583452855, 85.5641242711505, 
75.4154856775423), lat = c(33.7066861126216, 14.7103409600977, 
20.5129916361452, 27.5703696825569, 23.5382000019923, 19.4517685463546, 
10.4515827401328, 26.5845654103506, 28.6433836730517, 15.7549664734525, 
26.9232961978376, 22.6974841269408, 23.8143407874487, 23.3070171585463, 
30.1564981917953, 26.3553441447585, 29.198093425323, 31.92360060294, 
23.6561315040147, 30.8424285351448), Type = c("Union Territory", 
"State", "State", "State", "State", "State", "State", "State", 
"Union Territory", "State", "State", "State", "State", "State", 
"State", "State", "State", "State", "State", "State"), low_prestige = c(1000, 
836, 195, 1000, 188, 441, 441, 736, 370, 235, 0, 151, 82, 42, 
28, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), high_prestige = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 53, 149, 212, 
264, 630, 765, 808, 849, 918, 958, 972, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 
1000)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

The code that I have tried:

```
map1<-ggplot(final.plot1, aes( x = long, y = lat, group=id)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = low_prestige), color = "black")
map1
```

Comment: Your data contains only one observation per region it would try with `geom_point` instead of `geom_polygon`.

Comment: Adding to what @stefan says, a polygon is made up of more than one point, but you only have one point per state. What were you expecting would be drawn here? Like where would the polygon boundaries come from?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using the [`sf`](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/) package which is useful to plot geographic data in combination with `ggplot`. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.10.2, GDAL 3.4.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

your_sf <- st_as_sf(final.plot1, coords = c('long', 'lat'))
                  
ggplot(your_sf) +
  geom_sf(aes(color = low_prestige))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>